# Is it possible the get Azure AD user information in Blazor Server application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, blazor-server-side

My application uses Azure AD to login and that part works fine.
Now I want to give users access to different parts of the application by there AD Groups.
How can I do that?

And is it possible to not log the user in if he/she is not a member of that group?

I did try a lot of different things, and I also got some AD information, but  not the groups.

Answer (score 1):

Because you received a token doesn't mean you have access to all information associated to that user. The token only contains a basic set of information mostly to identify the user and their authorizations for the scope of the token.

What you should do is assign roles to the app registration and then assign your groups to the specific roles. The roles will appear in your token and you can then determine their permissions using those on your blazor app.

If you need information on the groups you could add permissions to your app registration for the Microsoft Graph API. You can then call the Graph API to get information about groups and similar features. For permissions you should stick to the roles and scopes though.

Comment: Thanks. I did assign a role to the app registration.
How do I access it then i C#?
Its not in the data I am receiving at the moment?

Comment: That depends on the SDK that you're using to handle the authentication/authorization.  The SDK usually exposes some easy way to check the roles for you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to NotFound's answer.  Checking the role in Blazor is not difficult.  Your should have an `AuthenticationState`.  In class, setup that parameter

```
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState>? authenticationState { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
```

Then in `OnInitialized` I call authenticationState which will give you your user and you can call `IsInRole().  I do this on my index page and then store it in session storage.

```
        var authState = await authenticationState;
        var user = authState?.User;
        await Storage.SetAsync("IsTaxApprover", user.IsInRole("TaxonomyApprover"));
```

I had to read this article five times before it sunk in.  Its worth the effort: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

It is working now, thanks for the help.